# TagHelper intellisense broken with VS 2019 16.5?

Tags: asp.net-core, intellisense, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I updated Visual Studio 2019 from version 16.4.5 to 16.5 last night. In doing so, the Razor Pages Tag Helpers seem to have lost their AutoComplete abilities.

```
@model Some.Namespace.MyModel
<label asp-for="[Used.to.AutoComplete.for.MyModel.Properties]"></label>
```

I should say that it isn't entirely broken. I can still use `@Model.Property`, it just no longer lists the properties without the `@Model.`.

I've tried clearing the MEF cache, re-installing the .Net Core 3.1.2 SDK, and repairing the VS2019 install. Is anyone else experiencing this with the latest version? Any additional ideas on things to try in order to fix?

Comment: I advice that you could ask on the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/topics/Visual+Studio+2019+Version+16.5.html)

Comment: I have the exact same problem.  Like, you `asp-for="@Model.Property"` will auto-suggest, whereas `asp-for="Property"` won't.

My quick addendum is that Intellisense is smart enough to flag `asp-for="PropertyMisspelled"` with a red squiggly, so it clearly knows what's going on, just won't auto-complete